# How to change the internal links of a muted node?

Tags: python, node-editor, shaders, geometry-nodes

[image]
i need this node to not destroy my nodetree when muted.. am i missing something?

It seems that python give us no possibilities too, `node.internal_links` has no `.new()` function, `node.internal_links.from/to_sockets` is read only, and if we try `node.links.new()` on the same node for a input/output we'll have a feedback loop error in the console

Comment: If this is not possible, I’d definitely suggest you post it as a feature request on rightclickselect.com and I’ll upvote.

Comment: as a workaround: using a switch node?

Comment: In what way is muting destroying your node tree?  I suspect the problem isn't directly with muting but with the internal wiring of the node group that node represents.  Could this be the case?

Comment: it looks like a bug tbh, in the doc it says that a muted node shouldn't change anything